# I create a for with email validation in angular but without validation the will be stored. how to solve this

Tags: html, angular

When I entered Email address
example: if I entered abc it shows alret "please enter valid email", If I kept blank to submit it shows alret "email required" But If I click register the data when these alrets will come My data saved
If I get any one alert The data should not save
what I have to change my code

below is the "registration.component.html"

```
<div class="container register-form">
 
    <div class="form">
        <div class="note">
         <h1>Employee Registration</h1>
 
        </div>

        <div>
            <form name="myForm" >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="names" for="empName"><span class="req">* </span> Employee Name: </label>
                        <input  type="text"  class="form-control is-invalid" [(ngModel)]="emp.empName" name="empName" required id="empName"
                            class="form-control phone"  maxlength="28"  />     </div>

                    <div class="form-group" >
                        <label for="empEmail"> Employee EmailId: </label>
                        <input id="empEmail" required [email]="emp.empEmail!==''" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="emp.empEmail"  
                           #emailControl ="ngModel" name="empEmail"  type="email"  /> 
                           <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf = "(emailControl.touched) && (emailControl.invalid)" style="margin-top: 3px;">
                                            
                        <span class="help-block" *ngIf="emailControl.errors?.required && emailControl.touched">Employee Email is required</span>
                                             
                        <span class="help-block" *ngIf = "emailControl.errors?.email && emailControl.touched">Invalid Email </span>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
<button style="margin-left: 450px; width: 100px;" (click)="registerNow()" type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' >Register</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the "registration.component.ts"

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration',
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration.component.css']
})
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

  emp:any={
    empEmail:''
  };
  message: any;
  submitted: boolean;
  myForm = new FormGroup({
    empName: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    empEmail: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    empAge: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    empSal: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
   
  });

  constructor(private service:EmpRegistrationService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  
  public registerNow(){
let resp =this.service.doRegistration(this.emp);
resp.subscribe((data)=>this.message=data);

  }
```

Can u please clear this
I dont want save the data when I got the invalid email or empty email filed

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', [Validators.required, ValidationService.emailValidator]],
  profile: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]]
});
```

}

```
  saveUser() {
    if (this.userForm.dirty && this.userForm.valid) {
      alert(
        `Name: ${this.userForm.value.name} Email: ${this.userForm.value.email}`
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is to disable the submit button if the form is invalid:

```html
<button [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Register</button>
```

Comment: yes I tried if I enter correct email address also it not enabled

Comment: Please bind your html form to your formGroup like so `[formGroup]="myForm"` and fill in all fields (they are all required)

If you want to check for valid email address you will need to add `Validators.email` to the validators array for your empEmail field.

Comment: This tutorial covers everything you need: https://blog.jscrambler.com/building-user-registration-form-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-7/